# Why does Data.Vector.Mutable read() return in the monad since its an immutable operation?

Tags: haskell, vector

Looking here http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.3/docs/Data-Vector-Mutable.html
One can see that the type of read is:

```hs
read :: PrimMonad m => MVector (PrimState m) a -> Int -> m a
```

Since read operation does not modify the vector, my main question is why is it not:

```hs
read :: PrimMonad m => MVector (PrimState m) a -> Int -> a
```

The length of a mutable vector is also doing something immutable on a vector, and its type is  `MVector s a -> Int` which looks normal. It is not `PrimMonad m => MVector (PrimState m) a -> m Int`.
So why was this difference of design choice made between read and length since they are both immutable operations on a vector?

Now that I think about it, could it be somehow that the cell returned by read is a reference to the cell inside the vector and not a copy of its data?
If so how can I nicely and cheaply get immutable access to the n-th element in a mutable vector? I'm learning haskell and not too sure about details.

Thanks,

Comment: Looking through the source, I found that `read` is ultimately implemented as [`readArray` from `Data.Primitive.Array`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.7.0.0/docs/Data-Primitive-Array.html#v:readArray) which already has this monadic signature. I did not dig deeper, but since it's a part of standard library, one can find out the specific details of implementation, likely C-based.

Comment: @9000 It's not about implementation. It's about semantics. A pure `read` is fundamentally impossible.

Comment: @HTNW: I see; I just wanted to notice that it's not the `MVector`'s decision.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume

```
read :: MVector s a -> Int -> a
```

which means `read` is pure. Consider

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  cell <- replicate 1 'a' -- cell = ['a']
  print $ read cell 1 -- we want to print 'a'
  write cell 1 'z' -- cell = ['z']
  print $ read cell 1 -- we want to print 'z'
```

Something's gone wrong: I wrote `read cell 1` twice, passing *the same* `cell` and `1` arguments, so the two calls should return the same value. That's what it means for `read` to be pure. The above should be equal to

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  cell <- replicate 1 'a' -- cell = ['a']
  let contents = read cell 1 -- contents = 'a'
  print contents -- prints 'a'
  write cell 1 'z' -- cell = ['z']; definitely should not affect contents
  print contents -- prints 'a'
```

But we don't want that: we want `read` to return different things even when we pass the same arguments, taking into account any `write`s that might have happened in between. Therefore, `read` must be a monadic action.

This is different from `length`. A vector's length never changes, even if the vector is mutable; the length fixed at creation. Therefore, `length` *is* a pure function; it doesn't matter what monadic actions you've performed between creating a vector and querying its length; it will always be the same.

Comment: I asked this some time ago but now I realize something. Perhaps the monadic read should not exist and one should be forced to unsafe freeze a vector, to read its pure version. This approach common in other languages allows just one version of read, and the implementer of read is unable to change the vector which is good but, unsafeFreeze might be unsafe if badly used. In haskell, practice is to have both a pure and monadic version. Thats more code and implementer of monadic read is not disallowed to change the vector which is also bad. In any approach there seems to be unsafe sides.

Comment: @jam What would that actually protect against? Presumably whatever nasty thing an implementer might choose to do in `read` they could also choose to do in `freeze`.

Answer (score 5):

Consider

```
foo = do
   ...
   x1 <- read vector 3
   write vector 3 something
   x2 <- read vector 3
   return (x1 == x2)
```

If `read` becomes non monadic, we can instead write this

```
foo = do
   ...
   let x1 = read vector 3
   write vector 3 something
   let x2 = read vector 3
   return (x1 == x2)
```

which is equivalent, by referential transparency, to

```
foo = do
   ...
   let x1 = read vector 3
   write vector 3 something
   let x2 = x1
   return (x1 == x2)
```

Here, we have an issue: the last snippet always returns `True` at the end, while the first one does not. So the two snippets are not really equivalent.

Reading must be considered an effect, not because it is observable from outside (it is not), but because it produces a different result depending on the state of the vector, which is effected by writes.

Comment: @J.M. Great question: if we could resize the mutable vector, it should definitely be an effect! However, `MVector a` does not allow resizing (`grow` creates a new larger vector instead, AFAICS), so `length` can be non-monadic.