# Why is MVector not Foldable?

Tags: haskell

May I understand why the `MVector` type(from `vector` package) doesn't instance the `Foldable` type class?
I suppose people would often need to iterate over vectors. I can `freeze` it to `Data.Vector` and then iterate. But I hate transforming these things, as if we don't do it enough with `String`, `Text`, `Bytestring`s etc.

In my case I'd like to print each element.

Comment: An `MVector` is in essence a *reference* to a vector, you thus need to *read* to obtain the data contained in the vector. An `MVector` is also not much more than a wrapper of a [`MutableArray`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.7.1.0/docs/Data-Primitive-Array.html#t:MutableArray) with two indexes.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm trying to implement QuickSort in Haskell. Is `MVector` a good choice in this case? I can't tell the difference between reference or real vectors

Comment: Any mutable container can not be iterated over as if it were an immutable container. The reason is the same why we can't use an `IORef Int` as if it were an `Int`. Roughly, immutable data can be read and used anywhere, without having to specify when that read happens wrt other side effects (since it will always read the same value). Instead, mutable data can only be read (and written) inside some monad that forces one to sequence side effects.

Comment: @chi yes, [except...](https://github.com/haskell/vector/issues/334)

Comment: Why is `MVector` not `Foldable`? Because you can't read data from an `MVector` outside of its monad. Why can't you read data from an `MVector` outside of a monad? [Because that would be impure.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58330593/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading from a mutable vector requires doing effects in the associated monad -- `IO` or `ST s`. But `Foldable` requires you to be able to produce a pure answer; if there were an instance, we would have to be able to at least implement

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> MVector s a -> b
```

even when the caller chooses a `b` that doesn't mention `IO` or `ST`. Whoops!